# The impact of allowing the reward to be negative in a contextual bandit problem

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-armed-bandits, contextual-bandits

I posted [this question on stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/625481/44368) 3 days ago. But there has been no answer. I would like to try my luck here.

---

It seems the contextual bandits problems, as shown in these two papers [Tong Mu, Yash Chandak, Tatsunori Hashimoto, Emma Brunskill: *Factored DRO: Factored Distributionally Robust Policies for Contextual Bandits*](https://openreview.net/forum?id=k6WzeLZjxuP), and [Nian Si, Fan Zhang, Zhengyuan Zhou, Jose Blanchet: *Distributionally Robust Batch Contextual Bandits*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.05630), generally assumes the reward $R$ are bounded $0<R<M$. I am wondering what would be impacted if $R$ is allowed to be negative.

Comment: unofficially: none, sound RL method are indifferent to reward function shifting... however, I can tell you all the stories you want in the practical side of RL, but i'm not a theory person, so can't help you with the papers

Comment: @Alberto: I would tend to agree. But this seems to be a standard assumption in the contextual bandits problem. Why?

Comment: Gave a veery quick look at the papers and seems just one of those assumptions that you can make to have an easier life proving stuff without loss of generality (since other cases can be mapped to this bounded positive case)

Comment: @Alberto: Could you be more specific after reading more deeply into the papers? Much appreciated.